# Apply a height to a static uitableviewcell in viewdidload method

Tags: ios, objective-c

Probably a simple question - but i'm reasonably new to IOS dev -

I would like to apply a height of 0 to a static uitableviewcell on load - which I can animate according to logic further down the line - but i'm not quite sure how to do it!

How can I apply a height to

```
_datePickRow.frame.size.height
```

Comment: is the cell created with a Ui file like a storyboard or .xib or is it in code?

Comment: Hi Simon - Its a Storyboard

Comment: hang on I think I misread your question, I take it from `_datePickRow ` you have a reference to the row. Are you simply asking how to set its height ? not where / how to get a reference to it

Comment: hi simon - yes - sorry I'm actually trying to hide a datepicker in a static uitableviewcell and animate its height and visibility when - basically trying to implememt the following - http://www.andrashatvani.com/2013/10/inline-date-picker-with-static-cells.html

Comment: Sorry took so long to get back, did you try the code in my answer. Is it what your looking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your asking simply how to set the height via code its:

```
[_datePickRow setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 0)]; // (x, y, width, height)
```

If your asking how to set the height and get a ref to the cell you can do the following. Be aware this will run everytime the tableView is reloaded so make sure you have a boolean switch inside to stop it:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexpath.row == 0 && !animated)
       return 0;
    else
       return 44;
}
```